# Facebook SDK : Sending Request from Page Tab App

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

I can send requests to friends using "Multi Friend Request Selector" inside my Page Tab App, which link looks like :

```
https://www.facebook.com/<my_page_name>/app_<my_app_id>
```

My friend receives my request, and click "Accept". It forwards to the real link of the Facebook App, which is :

```
https://apps.facebook.com/<my_app_name>/?fb_source=request&request_ids=<an_request_id>
```

which is not inside a Page Tab anymore. How can I forward to user to the 1st link instead of the 2nd while the request_ids have to be kept? Do I just make a `header('Location: url');` forwarding?

p.s. Timeline is already in use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you have to forward to your page url, because requests **always** redirect to the canvas url.

To pass the request ids you can use the `app_data` field. So instead of redirecting to `https://www.facebook.com/<my_page_name>/app_<my_app_id>` you redirect to `https://www.facebook.com/<my_page_name>/app_<my_app_id>?app_data=requestids`. Here requestids are the **actual values**(the comma separated list that the canvas gets).

`app_data` is available to your page tab app as part of the `signed_request` it receives.

From [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/):

> In addition, your app will also receive a string parameter called app_data as part of signed_request if an app_data parameter was set in the original query string in the URL your tab is loaded on. For the Shop Now link above, that could look like this: "https://www.facebook.com/YourPage?v=app_1234567890&app_data=any_string_here". You can use that to customize the content you render if you control the generation of the link.

Comment: Almost perfect answer. The redirect link should be: `https://www.facebook.com/<my_page_name>/app_<my_app_id>?app_data=requestids` and PHP `header('Location: url')` does not work in this case. Need to use client-side JavaScript redirects.

Comment: glad it helped..i didn't mention anything about `header` coz it does work sometimes, (when you haven't sent any output to the browser yet), afaik. the url, i wasn't so sure about this form of it, i'm used to the older style, `https://www.facebook.com/YourPage?v=app_1234567890&app_data=any_string_here` . anyway thanks, i learnt something too.

Comment: FYI, both format of URL works, but Facebook seems to prefer my version after changed to Timeline, as it is the default link format of Timeline.